# How to click on Element in Canvas using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, canvas, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to click on first canvas element but it is not taking any click. I tried by following ways:

**First way**

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//div[@id = 'cy']/div/canvas")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).perform()
```

**Second Way**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//div[@id = 'cy']/div/canvas").click()
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="cy">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 1029px; height: 130px;">
<canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 1029px; height: 130px;" data-id="layer0-selectbox" width="1029" height="130"></canvas>
<canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 4; width: 1029px; height: 130px;" data-id="layer1" width="1029" height="130"></canvas>
<canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; width: 1029px; height: 130px;" data-id="layer2-drag" width="1029" height="130"></canvas>
<canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 1029px; height: 130px;" data-id="layer3" width="1029" height="130"></canvas>
<canvas style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 1029px; height: 130px;" data-id="layer4-node" width="1029" height="130"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is happening? Are you sure the canvas is actually clickable? What are you expecting on click? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe nothing is happening when I click on image. Manually it opens a dailog message when clicked

Answer (score 1):

Try `move_to_element_with_offset`, it should work for you:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.html#ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset

Comment: The problem is that the co-ordinates of <div id= "cy" , <div style and <canvas are same. When I get the co-ordinates of element at id = "cy" it gives me x= 148 and y = 322, and also gives me same co-ordinates for element at div under div id = cy. So it is not taking click.

Comment: yes it works. when I click on Image it opens a small dailog message